# $f(g(x))=x$ implies $f(x)=g^{-1}(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Is it possible to find a necessary and sufficient condition to conclude when
$$f(g(x))=x \implies f(x)=g^{-1}(x) \wedge f^{-1}(x)=g(x),$$
if both functions are well defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If either $f$ is injective or $g$ is surjective, then $f\circ g={\rm id}$ implies $\exists f^{-1},g^{-1}$ then necessarily $f^{-1}=g$ and $g^{-1}=f$.

Comment: Is this sufficient condition also necessary?

Comment: $f^{-1}=g$ itself implies $g^{-1}=f$ and $f\circ g={\rm id}$. Also, $\exists f^{-1}$ means $f$ is bijective. So, necessary and sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $f,g\colon X\to X$, then $f^{-1}=g$ if and only if $f\circ g=g\circ f=\text{Id}_X$